# Yahoo finance webservice API direct to ?bypass=true

Tags: web-services, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Refer to the [Yahoo finance webservice API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543776/yahoo-finance-webservice-api), I unable to find http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO,AAPL/quote?format=json&view=detail

It shows 'Not a valid parameter'.
I also discover it will direct to ?bypass=true
How can I view the json data?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that json is only supported through Yahoo Query Language (yql) API. The API endpoint is `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql` and you have to submit the query in the form  as (prefixed with ?) `q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('symbol1,symbol2')`, you must also specify the format as `format=json`, you may also need to specify an environment in order for the data to be return correctly based on certain schema. So far I found `env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys` works for me. The entire url of course has to be url-encoded, you can run a curl command to test it out (replace with actual stock symbol):

```
curl -G http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql? --data-urlencode "q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('symbol1, symbol2') --data-urlencode "format=json" --data-urlencode "env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
```

For more information, please check [YQL Guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/). It took me hours of reading and try-and-error to make it work!